# Sharing violation in modifying files with Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

When I open any excel file with Excel 2010 which were saved in Excel 2003/2007, It creates some temporary file of same size in the same folder and I get following error message;

> "When saving a file, a sharing violation can be caused by the way an
>   antivirus application interacts with Microsoft Office.
>
> Check with your antivirus provider to make sure that the current
>   version of the application, including updates, is installed. The
>   antivirus provider might also have information or solutions for
>   sharing violation issues."

If I delete the temporary file then sometimes it lets me save the excel.

If I create new file in Excel 2010, I don't face such error.

What should I do?

Comment: Please [edit] you questions and add details to the following; Did you check with your antivirus provider? Which one are you using? Are these files you created? Are they saved locally in a trusted location?

Comment: I am using bitdefender. I have tried after disabling antivirus and firewall. I was not facing any such problem with office 2007 or 2003 but with 2010. I have files locally on another drive. I have 2 OS installed. Yes, I am accessing files created by myself

Comment: Well!! I have installed Excel 2007. Now not facing such problem every time.